FX rates downloaded base on criteria
I would like to recevie "Bgt Avg YTD" for specific material. And later use it for calculation (Bgt Avg YTD * Value)
FX Rates



Currency
Bgt Avg YTD
Reporting date




USD
1,12
31.01.2024


USD
1.23
31.03.2024


EUR
1,12
31.01.2024


EUR
1.23
31.03.2024



Currency



Currency




USD


EUR



Reporting date



Reporting date




31.01.2024


31.03.2024



GRIP



Material No
Purchase curr
Plant
Reporting date
Value




123A
USD
1111
31.01.2024
100


123A
USD
2222
31.01.2024
350


122B
USD
1111
31.01.2024
400


123A
EUR
4444
31.01.2024
140


122B
EUR
4444
31.01.2024
840


122B
EUR
6666
31.01.2024
660



The challenge that I have is that Currency is not unique in "FX Rates" table and I would like to receive it base on slicer "Reporting date".
GRIP has only one Reporting date (31.01.2024).
Connections that I have are

I've tried to create measure
Miara test = CALCULATE(SUM('FX Rates'[Bgt Avr YTD]),DATESMTD('Reporting date'[Reporting date])) 

But I receive some total value, not correct FX rate.

I created two calculated columns on the GRIP table. To get the Bgt Avg YTD on the GRIP table, I recommend using a LOOKUPVALUE  function searching both the Currency and the Reporting Date to bring back one value.
Bgt Avg YTD = 
LOOKUPVALUE('FX Rates'[Bgt Avg YTD], 'FX Rates'[Currency], GRIP[Purchase curr], 'FX Rates'[Reporting date], GRIP[Reporting date])

calculation = GRIP[Value] * GRIP[Bgt Avg YTD]



The following works as well:
 Bgt Avg YTD =  = 
VAR Purch_curr = MAXX('GRIP','GRPI'[Purchase curr])
RETURN(
(CALCULATE(AVERAGEX('FX Rates','FX Rates'[[Bgt Avr YTD]),DATESYTD('Reporting date'[Date]),'Currency'[Currency]= Purch_curr))

